# ピンチイン後に画像を縦スクロールできない

Tags: objective-c, uiscrollview

現在画面中央に表示されている画像をピンチインで拡大させ、その状態で画像を端から端までスクロールして見れるようなプログラムを作っているのですが、なぜか画像をピンチインで拡大した後に縦スクロールができません。横スクロールはできます。また、ピンチイン後に少し画像が下にズレます。何かそれが縦スクロールできないことに関係している気もするのですが......。下記にコードを記します。どなたか分かる方がいれば教えていただきたいです。すみませんが、よろしくお願いします。

ImageScaleViewController.h

```
@interface ImageScaleViewController : UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) UIImageView *scaleImageView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;

@end
```

ImageScaleViewController.m

```
UIImageView *scaleImageView;

@implementation ImageScaleViewController

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:YES];

    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];

    scaleImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.scaleImageView.center.x - self.scaleImageView.bounds.size.width / 2, self.scaleImageView.center.y - self.scaleImageView.bounds.size.height / 2, self.scaleImageView.bounds.size.width, self.scaleImageView.bounds.size.height)];
    scaleImageView.image = self.scaleImageView.image;

    [self.scrollView addSubview:scaleImageView];

    [self imageScaleByAffine];

    [self setPinchGesture];
}

- (void)imageScaleByAffine {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2f animations:^{
        scaleImageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, scaleImageView.frame.size.width * 2, scaleImageView.frame.size.height * 2);
        scaleImageView.center = self.view.center;
    }];
}

- (void)setPinchGesture {
    self.scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 2.0;
    self.scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 3.0;
}

- (UIView*)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    return scaleImageView;
}

@end
```

Comment: あなたには、CGAffineTransformは、オブジェクトの位置、サイズ、角度を変えるものではなくて、座標を変換するものだと、アドバイスさしあげたことがあるのだけど、それを認識した上で、CGAffineTransformをお使いになってるのですか？そしてその使用がトラブルの原因になっているのではないかという疑いはもたれないのですか？すくなくとも、それは関係ないということを、明確にしてから、質問なさるべきだと思いますよ。

Comment: 変数scaleImageViewがダブっているのですが、これはどういう意図でそうなさっているのですか？

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。試しにImageViewのサイズ自体をscaleImageView.frame = CGRectMakeというようにして実際にサイズを拡大させて試してみると、縦スクロールはできるようになったのですが、画像の下までスクロールすることなく途中でスクロールが止まってしまいます。また、これもピンチインした後に画像が少し下にスライドしてズレました。
確かに変数scaleImageViewがダブっているので名前を変えようと思います。意図ではなく間違いでした。

Comment: 現状、あなたのプログラムはどうなっているのですか？随時質問文中の、サンプルコードを変更して、回答する意思のある人が、コピーして、問題を再現できるようにしないと、だれも問題点を指摘できないでしょう。

Comment: 質問文のコードを変更しました。変更したのはimageScaleByAffine内です。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ImageScaleViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
// ここから引用しよう。
@interface ImageScaleViewController : UIViewController <UIScrollViewDelegate>
// UIScrollViewDelegateを組みこまないと、DelegateメソッドviewForZoomingInScrollView:が動かないのでは？

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *scaleImageView;
// なぜ、これにIBOutletが付いてない？
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;

@end
```

ImageScaleViewController.m

```
#import "ImageScaleViewController.h"

@implementation ImageScaleViewController {
    UIImageView *scaleImageView;
    // インスタンス変数は、ここに記述する。元コードの位置のままだと、それはC言語のグローバル変数。
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    // [super viewDidAppear:YES];
    [super viewDidAppear: animated];
    // 特別な意図がない限り、スーパークラスには、引数に手を加えず、そのまま渡す。

    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];

    scaleImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.scaleImageView.bounds.size.width, self.scaleImageView.bounds.size.height)];
    // scaleImageViewの左上の座標を{0, 0}以外にしても、意味ありません。詳しい説明はあとで。
    scaleImageView.image = self.scaleImageView.image;
    self.scrollView.contentSize = scaleImageView.bounds.size;
    // この1行挿入で、問題は解決しているはず。
    [self.scrollView addSubview:scaleImageView];

    [self imageScaleByAffine];

    [self setPinchGesture];
}

- (void)imageScaleByAffine {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2f animations:^{
        self.scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake((scaleImageView.bounds.size.width - self.scrollView.bounds.size.width) / 2.0, (scaleImageView.bounds.size.height - self.scrollView.bounds.size.height) / 2.0);
        // scrollView中央に、scaleImageViewを位置させる。scaleImageViewの位置（center）をいじっても意味ありません。スクロールビュー内のコンテンツの位置は、UIScrollViewのプロパティcontentOffsetで調節します。
    }];
}

- (void)setPinchGesture {
    self.scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 2.0;
    self.scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 3.0;
    // どちらかの値を1.0にすべきだと思う。あるいは、最小値が1.0より小さく、最大値が1.0より大きくする。そうしないと、最初ピンチしたときのふるまいが、ユーザに奇妙な印象を与える。
}

- (UIView*)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    return scaleImageView;
}

@end
```

解説は、すべてコメントで記述したので、ここに書き記すことはありません。

Comment: scaleImageView.centerではなく、scrollView.contentOffsetを使うことで丁度の位置でズーム後にスクロールを行うことができました！たいへんありがとうございました。